# Modifying binary file with Python

Tags: python, file-io, binaryfiles

i am trying to patch a hex file.
i have two patch files (hex) named "patch 1" and "patch 2"

the file to be patched is a 16 MB file named "file.bin".

i have tried many different way for the past 6 or 7 hours to figure out how to do it. I can write a string to a file all day long, but i am trying to do the following:

open patch1.bin with read bytes
open patch2.bin with read bytes
open file.bin with write bytes

i want to seek to positions 0xc0010, and 0x7c0010, and apply patch1.bin
then i want to seek to 0x040000 and apply patch2.bin

so all in all i will have 3 patches applied, then close the "file.bin"

if someone cold give me an example i would very much appreciate it :)

i tried this first:

```
patch1 = open("patch1", "r");
patch2 = open("patch2", "r");
main = open("file.bin", "w");

main.seek(0xC0010);
main.write(patch1);
main.seek(0x7C0010);
main.write(patch1);
main.seek(0x40000);
main.write(patch2);
main.close();
```

but was informed i was was trying to write a string to a file, when indeed its not what i wanted, lol
then i tried this:

```
infile1 = open("patch1.bin", "rb") 
new_pos1 = int("0x00", 16)
infile1.seek(new_pos1, 0)
infile2 = open('file.bin', 'wb')
new_pos2 = int('0xc0010', 16)
infile2.seek(new_pos2, 0xc0010)
chunk1 = int("6FFFE0", 16)         #this is how long patch1 file is
data1 = infile1.read(chunk1)
with open("file.bin", "a") as outfile:
    outfile.write(data1)
```

but it did not work either, as no matter what i tried, i could not get it to write the data at he correct offset.

I did manage a few times to write the patch1 to file.bin, but it did not patch at the right offset, as a matter of fact it deleted the file.bin and just copied patch1 in its place. which ofcourse is wrong.

i must remind you i am new to python and programming, but i am really trying to dig my feet into it and learn, so any good examples will be examined and hopefully will be a good learning lesson for me :)

thanks guys and gals for helping me figure out what i was doing wrong :)

Comment: What did you try? Quote your code.

Comment: That is not a "hex file"; it's a *binary* file. A hex file would be a text file containing hexadecimal numbers. These are often used to *represent* binary data, when you want to work with text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You only need to use `seek` and `write`. Use `seek` to jump to the position and `write` to overrwite the existing data.

```
with file('patch1.bin', 'rb') as fh:
    patch1 = fh.read()

with file('patch2.bin', 'rb') as fh:
    patch2 = fh.read()

with file('file.bin', 'r+b') as fh:
    # apply patch1
    fh.seek(0xc0010)
    fh.write(patch1)
    fh.seek(0x7c0010)
    fh.write(patch1)
    # apply patch2
    fh.seek(0x040000)
    fh.write(patch2)
```

Comment: ok i figured out what it was, with file('file.bin', 'w') needed to be 'r+'.... after i changed that the code works flawless. thank you very much :)

Comment: When opening the patch files, you should open them in binary mode - `open("<fn>", "rb")`, while the file to be patched should be opened in "r+b" mode.

Comment: `w` mode truncates the file. Use `r+b` for patching existing file.

Comment: well, i tested the files byte for byte, and when i run the script, it is different than when i manually patch the file, i tested with HxD and use file compare function. is there a way to make it more accurate?

Comment: nvm, i figured it out. while i was screwing things up, i managed to delete all the data in one of my patch files, lol. i recopied it and all is well and the files are identical. thanks everyone :)

Comment: Whops. Fixed the code example. Sorry, I only tested it against an empty file created usind `dd if=/dev/zero of=file.bin count=50000` and everything seamed to be ok.

Comment: When dealing with large files, maybe you should consider using mmap instead of file.read etc.

Answer (score 3):

1.txt:

```
asdf
```

a.py:

```
with open('1.txt','r+b') as f:
    f.seek(2)
    f.write('D')
```

1.txt:

```
asDf
```

This should give you a clue.

Comment: yes, and i now know what i was doing worng ;) thanks for schooling a noob lol

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `r+b` mode for editing the target file. `wb` is the mode for writing without updating and will truncate an existing file. Check out http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open or your OS' man page for fopen to get details on the different file modes.

Comment: `w+b` truncates the file. Use `r+b` in this case.