# how to write to a specific part of file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want replace a specific part of file by bytes, here's an ugly image to explain what i want to achieve:-

[image]

i tried to do it with this code

```
f=open('a.txt')
f.seek(250, os.SEEK_SET)
print(f.read(750))
```

it works fine, but it only reads the file, not actually writes to the file.
i tried to use this code

```
f=open('a.txt')
f.seek(250, os.SEEK_SET)
print(f.write('data', 750))
```

but `write` only takes 1 argument, so i can't use `write` command.

are there any methods i can achieve this in python?

Comment: For not-very-large file it would probably be faster to just read the whole file, change the part you need, and write it back.

Comment: Do you want to replace those 500 bytes with just 4 bytes (and shift the rest to the left)?

Comment: your question isn't very clear. replace the data in [250 - 750] with what?

Comment: `open('a.txt')` opens the file for reading by default, so a `f.write()` isn't going to work. You need to read the entire file to get the parts you want to keep, and then re-open the file in write mode and output the two sections you want to retain.

Comment: Related to [Modifying binary file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643538/modifying-binary-file-with-python)

Comment: @user202729 no, i want to replace the 500 bytes with 500 new bytes of data, not shifting the bytes

Comment: @martineau i tried to use your method but the performance is too slow, i need to look for a more ideal way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in the [appropriate mode](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open), seek the position you want and write the amount of bytes you want to replace. To replace everything from position 250 to 750, you need to write 500 bytes.

Bytes isn't really correct in this case though, because it seems to be a text file and it is opened in text mode. Use `"r+b"` if you really wanted binary mode.

```
with open("a.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.seek(250)
    print(f.read(500))
    f.seek(250)
    f.write("X"*500)
```

Comment: this works for txt files, but is there anyway i can achieve the same thing for .mp4 files?

Comment: Binary files like .mp4 can be opened with `"r+b"`. The data written to the file should be [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes). @kurdishdevil

Answer (score 1):

You should use open('a.txt', 'r+'), the first answer to this question [How to open a file for both reading and writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/how-to-open-a-file-for-both-reading-and-writing) has a good set up.